# delete cookie key value pair

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I am trying to delete a cookie by setting the expiry date time as follows. However the key of the cookie still exists. This only sets the cookie to the empty string. How to remove the key value pair of the cookie completely?

```
document.cookie = "username=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK deleting cookies set by the server can be tricky. In order to delete cookies set using JavaScript, use the following method:

```
function deleteCookie(c_name) {
    document.cookie = c_name+'=' + ";expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT ;domain=.yourdomain.com;path=/";
    document.cookie = c_name+'=' + ";expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT ;";
}
```

Just call this method as: `deleteCookie("username");`

Comment: the cookies is set by javascript. So it is not possible to remove the entire cookie (key and value) instead of setting the value to empty string? btw why in your delete cookie method one is include domain and path why other doesn't? doesn't it make redudancy?

Comment: Usually, the second call would suffice. But, when you wish to delete the cookie and it unavailable for sub-domains as well, that is when you need the `domain` and `path` parameters as well. Feel free to ignore the first line if the second one does the job for you.

Comment: but it still doesnt remove the key value pair of cookie ... it just set the value to empty string only and the key still exist